# EmguCV filter image for certain colors

Tags: c#, image, filtering, emgucv

For a current medical project I want to filter vaskularisation images to only show red and blue color. If possible I would also like to only show colored blobs over a certain size. In the following Images I have an example for one of these pictures I would like to analyse:
[Vaskularisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtXLL.png). 
I managed to filter it sofar that most of the noise is gone:
[Filtered Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr1RD.png)
. Now I would like to count the **colored** blobs in this image and display all which are bigger that a custom defined threshold. I am using EmguCV in C# for the image editing, but I have not found a way to select only the colored blobs. I would be grateful for any suggestions!